# Need dynamic variable names in C# for ebay feeds

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ebay-api

I need these varaible names to be dynamic.
To give you an example of what I'm looking at > https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1742

Now in the above link, it has some code for variaitons.

```
    //Specify Variations
    VariationTypeCollection VarCol = new VariationTypeCollection();

    //Variation 1 - Black S
    VariationType var1 = new VariationType();
    var1.SKU = "VAR1";
    var1.Quantity = 10;
    var1.StartPrice = new AmountType();
    var1.StartPrice.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
    var1.StartPrice.Value = 35;
    var1.VariationSpecifics = new NameValueListTypeCollection();

    NameValueListType Var1Spec1   = new NameValueListType();
    StringCollection Var1Spec1Valuecoll  = new StringCollection();

    Var1Spec1.Name = "Colour";
    Var1Spec1Valuecoll.Add("Black");
    Var1Spec1.Value = Var1Spec1Valuecoll;

    var1.VariationSpecifics.Add(Var1Spec1);

    NameValueListType Var1Spec2 = new NameValueListType();
    StringCollection Var1Spec2Valuecoll = new StringCollection();

    Var1Spec2.Name = "Size";
    Var1Spec2Valuecoll.Add("S");
    Var1Spec2.Value = Var1Spec2Valuecoll;

    var1.VariationSpecifics.Add(Var1Spec2);

    VarCol.Add(var1);

    //Variation 2 - Black L
    VariationType var2 = new VariationType();
    var2.SKU = "VAR2";
    var2.Quantity = 10;
    var2.StartPrice = new AmountType();
    var2.StartPrice.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
    var2.StartPrice.Value = 45;

    var2.VariationSpecifics = new NameValueListTypeCollection();

    NameValueListType Var2Spec1 = new NameValueListType();
    StringCollection Var2Spec1Valuecoll = new StringCollection();

    Var2Spec1.Name = "Colour";
    Var2Spec1Valuecoll.Add("Black");
    Var2Spec1.Value = Var2Spec1Valuecoll;

    var2.VariationSpecifics.Add(Var2Spec1);

    NameValueListType Var2Spec2 = new NameValueListType();
    StringCollection Var2Spec2Valuecoll = new StringCollection();

    Var2Spec2.Name = "Size";
    Var2Spec2Valuecoll.Add("L");
    Var2Spec2.Value = Var2Spec2Valuecoll;

    var2.VariationSpecifics.Add(Var2Spec2);

    VarCol.Add(var2);
```

So the code I'm working with I would Like dynamically create the varaible names, because as you can imagine there is no way for me to know how many variations each product has.

Sure i could count the amount of variations, and set up an if else structure

```
if (count == 1) {
     //some code
}
else if (count == 2) {
     //some code
}
```

But that doesn't seem like a good solution.

At the moment variables are required to be output inside a for each loop

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
string UPC = "";
                string Brand = "";
                string MPN = "";

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(product.Gtin))
                    UPC = product.Gtin;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ebayProduct.EbayProductBrandName))
                    Brand = ebayProduct.EbayProductBrandName;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(product.ManufacturerPartNumber))
                    MPN = product.ManufacturerPartNumber;

                //create the call object
                AddFixedPriceItemCall AddFPItemCall = new AddFixedPriceItemCall(context);

                AddFPItemCall.AutoSetItemUUID = true;

                //create an item object and set the properties
                ItemType item = new ItemType();

                //set the item condition depending on the value from GetCategoryFeatures
                item.ConditionID = 1000; //new

                //Basic properties of a listing
                item.Country = CountryCodeType.AU;
                item.Currency = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;

                //Track item by SKU
                item.InventoryTrackingMethod = InventoryTrackingMethodCodeType.SKU;
                item.SKU = ebayProduct.EbayProductSKU;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ebayProduct.EbayProductDescription))
                    item.Description = ebayProduct.EbayProductDescription;
                else
                    item.Description = "This product is brand new.";

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ebayProduct.EbayProductTitle))
                    item.Title = ebayProduct.EbayProductTitle;

                item.SubTitle = ebayProduct.EbayProductItemSubtitle;
                item.ListingDuration = "GTC";

                item.ItemSpecifics = new NameValueListTypeCollection();

                NameValueListTypeCollection ItemSpecs = new NameValueListTypeCollection();

                var productSpecAttributes = product.ProductSpecificationAttributes.ToList();

                foreach (var val in productSpecAttributes)
                {
                    StringCollection valueCol1 = new StringCollection();
                    NameValueListType nv1 = new NameValueListType();

                    nv1.Name = val.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute.Name.Replace(":", "");
                    valueCol1.Add(val.CustomValue);
                    nv1.Value = valueCol1;

                    ItemSpecs.Add(nv1);
                }

                item.ItemSpecifics = ItemSpecs;

                item.PaymentMethods = new BuyerPaymentMethodCodeTypeCollection();
                item.PaymentMethods.Add(BuyerPaymentMethodCodeType.PayPal);
                item.PayPalEmailAddress = "test@test.com";
                item.PostalCode = "5000";

                //Specify Shipping Services
                item.DispatchTimeMax = 3;
                item.ShippingDetails = new ShippingDetailsType();
                item.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions = new ShippingServiceOptionsTypeCollection();

                ShippingServiceOptionsType shipservice1 = new ShippingServiceOptionsType();
                shipservice1.ShippingService = "AU_Regular";
                shipservice1.ShippingServicePriority = 1;
                shipservice1.ShippingServiceCost = new AmountType();
                shipservice1.ShippingServiceCost.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
                shipservice1.ShippingServiceCost.Value = 1.0;

                shipservice1.ShippingServiceAdditionalCost = new AmountType();
                shipservice1.ShippingServiceAdditionalCost.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
                shipservice1.ShippingServiceAdditionalCost.Value = 1.0;

                item.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions.Add(shipservice1);

                ShippingServiceOptionsType shipservice2 = new ShippingServiceOptionsType();
                shipservice2.ShippingService = "AU_Express";
                shipservice2.ShippingServicePriority = 2;
                shipservice2.ShippingServiceCost = new AmountType();
                shipservice2.ShippingServiceCost.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
                shipservice2.ShippingServiceCost.Value = 4.0;

                shipservice2.ShippingServiceAdditionalCost = new AmountType();
                shipservice2.ShippingServiceAdditionalCost.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
                shipservice2.ShippingServiceAdditionalCost.Value = 1.0;

                item.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions.Add(shipservice2);

                //Specify Return Policy
                item.ReturnPolicy = new ReturnPolicyType();
                item.ReturnPolicy.ReturnsAcceptedOption = "ReturnsAccepted";

                item.StartPrice = new AmountType();
                item.StartPrice.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
                item.StartPrice.Value = Double.Parse(ebayProduct.EbayProductPrice.ToString());

                item.PrimaryCategory = new CategoryType();
                item.PrimaryCategory.CategoryID = ebayProduct.EbayCategoryID;

                item.ProductListingDetails = new ProductListingDetailsType();
                //Specifying UPC as the product identifier. Other applicable product identifiers
                //include ISBN, EAN, Brand-MPN.
                item.ProductListingDetails.UPC = UPC;

                //If multiple product identifiers are specified, eBay uses the first one that
                //matches a product in eBay's catalog system.
                item.ProductListingDetails.BrandMPN = new BrandMPNType();
                item.ProductListingDetails.BrandMPN.Brand = ebayProduct.EbayProductBrandName;
                item.ProductListingDetails.BrandMPN.MPN = product.ManufacturerPartNumber;

                //If multiple prod matches found, list the item with the 1st product's information
                item.ProductListingDetails.UseFirstProduct = true;

                //Add pictures
                item.PictureDetails = new PictureDetailsType();
                item.PictureDetails.PictureURL = new StringCollection();

                //Specify GalleryType
                item.PictureDetails.GalleryType = GalleryTypeCodeType.None;
                item.PictureDetails.GalleryTypeSpecified = true;
                /*
                 *  Handle Variations
                 */
                var childProducts = _productService.GetAssociatedProducts(product.Id);

                if (childProducts != null)
                {
                    //Specify VariationsSpecificsSet
                    item.Variations = new VariationsType();

                    item.Variations.VariationSpecificsSet = new NameValueListTypeCollection();

                    var colourSpec = productSpecAttributes.FirstOrDefault(
                                            x => x.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute.Name == "Colour");
                    var sizeSpec = productSpecAttributes.FirstOrDefault(
                                    x => x.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute.Name == "Size");


                    if (colourSpec != null && sizeSpec == null)
                    {
                        List<string> colourSpecsList = new List<string>();

                        foreach (var cp in childProducts)
                        {
                            var colourSpecs = cp.ProductSpecificationAttributes.FirstOrDefault(
                                                x => x.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute.Name == "Colour");

                            colourSpecsList.Add(colourSpecs.SpecificationAttributeOption.Name);
                        }
                        //sizes
                        NameValueListType NVListVS2 = new NameValueListType();
                        NVListVS2.Name = "Colour";
                        StringCollection VSvaluecollection2 = new StringCollection();
                        String[] Colour = colourSpecsList.ToArray();

                        VSvaluecollection2.AddRange(Colour);

                        NVListVS2.Value = VSvaluecollection2;
                        item.Variations.VariationSpecificsSet.Add(NVListVS2);
                    }

                    //Add Variation Specific Pictures
                    item.Variations.Pictures = new PicturesTypeCollection();

                    foreach (var cp in childProducts)
                    {
                        //Specify Variations
                        VariationTypeCollection VarCol = new VariationTypeCollection();


                        PicturesType pic = new PicturesType();

                        var specs = cp.ProductSpecificationAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttribute.Name == "Colour");
                        var childEbayProduct = _ebayProductService.GetEbayProductById(cp.Id);

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(specs.SpecificationAttributeOption.Name))
                        {
                            VariationType var1 = new VariationType();
                            var1.SKU = cp.RexProductId.ToString();
                            Debug.WriteLine(cp.RexProductId.ToString());
                            var1.Quantity = cp.StockQuantity;

                            var1.StartPrice = new AmountType();
                            var1.StartPrice.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.AUD;
                            var1.StartPrice.Value = Double.Parse(cp.Price.ToString());
                            var1.VariationSpecifics = new NameValueListTypeCollection();

                            NameValueListType Var1Spec1 = new NameValueListType();
                            StringCollection Var1Spec1Valuecoll = new StringCollection();

                            Var1Spec1.Name = "Colour";
                            Var1Spec1Valuecoll.Add(specs.SpecificationAttributeOption.Name);
                            Var1Spec1.Value = Var1Spec1Valuecoll;

                            var1.VariationSpecifics.Add(Var1Spec1);

                            //pics
                            pic.VariationSpecificName = "Colour";
                            pic.VariationSpecificPictureSet = new VariationSpecificPictureSetTypeCollection();
                            VariationSpecificPictureSetType VarPicSet1 = new VariationSpecificPictureSetType();
                            VarPicSet1.VariationSpecificValue = specs.SpecificationAttributeOption.Name;
                            StringCollection PicURLVarPicSet1 = new StringCollection();
                            PicURLVarPicSet1.Add(childEbayProduct.EbayProductMainImgUrl);
                            VarPicSet1.PictureURL = PicURLVarPicSet1;

                            pic.VariationSpecificPictureSet.Add(VarPicSet1);
                            item.Variations.Pictures.Add(pic);

                            VarCol.Add(var1);

                            item.Variations.Variation = VarCol;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Anyone know what I might be able to do here.
Cheers

Comment: I might be missing something here, but... just *loop*, with `.Add` at the bottom of the loop?

Comment: It seems you are taking a simplistic example that shows how to work with two variations and trying to extend to many.  That implies the need for an array of variations, rather than "dynamic variable names".

Comment: Ahh this is what I needed to do, move this code `item.Variations.Variation = VarCol;` underneath the loop and needed to move this code `VariationTypeCollection VarCol = new VariationTypeCollection();` above the loop. Now to figure out the problem with images @.@

Comment: THanks @MarcGravell

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to "dynamic variable names" is a Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>();
variables.Add("var1", "test1");
variables.Add("var2", "test2");
MessageBox.Show(variables["var1"]); // will display test1
```

If you have a set of needed data for each "variable", make a class or struct (maybe call it "TheData")

```
Dictionary<string, TheData> variables = new Dictionary<string, TheData>();
variables.Add("var1", new TheData() { price = 25.28, upc = "01121...", manufacturer = "ACME" });
```